# Como trabalhar com âncoras no ReacJS

Tags: react

Gostaria de chamar um id dentro da minha página html

Tipo:

```
<a href="#meuid">Meu id </a>
<section id="meuid>
   Meu Id
</section>
```

No React

Estou tentando assim:

**header.js**

```
    import { HashLink as Link} from 'react-router-hash-link'
    
    const Header = () => {
      return (
            <header id="header" className="header-transparent">
                <div className="container">
    
                    <div id="logo" className="pull-left">
                        <Link to="">
                            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" />
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                
    
                    <nav id="nav-menu-container">
                        <ul className="nav-menu">
                            <li className="menu-active"><Link smooth to="/">Home</Link></li>
                            <li><Link smooth to="/home#about">About Us</Link></li>
                            <li><Link smooth to="#services">Services</Link></li>
                            <li><Link smooth to="#portfolio">Portfolio</Link></li>
                            <li><Link smooth to="#team">Team</Link></li>                       
                            <li><Link smooth to="#contact">Contact Us</Link></li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
        )
    }

export default Header
```

**home.js**

```
import Header from '../../components/header';


const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div >
            <Header />
        
            <section id="hero">
                <div className="hero-container" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
                    <h1>Welcome to Regna</h1>
                    <h2>We are team of talented designers making websites with Bootstrap</h2>
                    <Link smooth to="#about" className="btn-get-started">Get Started</Link>
                </div>
            </section>

            <main>
               <section id="about">
                  <div className="container" data-aos="fade-up">
                      amount
                  </div>
                </section>



                <section id="services">
                    services
                </section>

        </div>
        );
    }
    
export default Home;
```

Porém o único lugar que funciona a âncora é do `<section id="hero">` e do componente Header não funciona

Como faço pra resolver?

Comment: não precisa usar o outro pacote! e também a pergunta nos links não tem a tag hero? como foi os testes

Comment: olha aqui também tem como colocar ancora: https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link

Comment: Cada um id diferente

Comment: eu fiz um exemplo é funcionou corretamente com o pacote adicional.

Comment: Acho que deve ser o template que usei, quando uso hot reload ele não funciona usando Angular, react ou vue

Answer (score 0):

Fala adventistaam!

Cara, o Link no ReactJS tem essa propriedade, mas nunca configurei, visto que ele é feito justamente para você navegar dentro do seu app.
Mas você pode dar uma olhada na docs (https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link) que lá mostra como colocar uma âncora na tag `<Link />`

Caso você opte por usar o `<a />` tem que trocar o Link por um `<a></a>` caso queria aquele efeito de escrolagem.

Reproduzi seu código aqui e deu certo, segue o exemplo:

```js
// import { HashLink as Link } from 'react-router-hash-link'

const Header = () => {
  return (
    <header id="header" className="header-transparent">
      <div className="container">

        <div id="logo" className="pull-left">
          <a href="/">
            <img src="assets/img/logo.png" alt="" />
          </a>
        </div>


        <nav id="nav-menu-container">
          <ul className="nav-menu">            
            <li><a href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
  )
}
```

Aqui só fiz uma gambiarra na tag  para poder coloco-lá la em baixo para poder ver o efeito do scrool sendo feito!

```js
import Header from './Header';


const Home = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Header />

      <section id="hero">
        <div className="hero-container" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
          <h1>Welcome to Regna</h1>
          <h2>We are team of talented designers making websites with Bootstrap</h2>
          <a href="#about" className="btn-get-started">Get Started</a>
        </div>
      </section>

      <main style={{ position: "relative", top: "1000px" }}>
        <section id="about" >
          <div className="container" data-aos="fade-up">
            amount
          </div>
        </section>



        <section id="services">
          services
        </section>
      </main>

    </div>
  );
}
```

Mas enfim, espero que tenha te ajudado! E também espero que você consiga encontrar uma forma de fazer com o `<Link />` do React.

Comment: Toda vez que clico em algum link do header ele volta para topo da página